# Simple JavaScript check not working?

Tags: javascript

I have this validate form function:

```
function ValidateForm() {
    var chks = document.register.elements['sendto[]'];
    var hasChecked = false;
    for (var i=0;i<chks.length;i++){
        if (chks[i].checked){
            hasChecked = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!hasChecked){
        alert("Please select at least one friend.");
        chks[0].focus();
        return false;
    }
}
```

html for this is:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="sendto[]" value="2" >
```

I know this is not full code. Full code is huge. But basically if i have only one checkbox in the code the above code gives a message undefined on ValidateForm(). Which is called when form is submitted and and above checkbox is checked.

But if i have two checkboxes in the code like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="sendto[]" value="2" >
<input type="checkbox" name="sendto[]" value="4" >
```

On submit when ValidateForm() function is called this works correctly. Am i doing something wrong that it is not working for 1 checkbox even if it is checked?

Comment: I'm assuming `register` is the name of his form.

Comment: @Gurnor how do u know the message is undefined? are u checking in  the console?

Comment: not to sound like a dick or anything but maybe you need to put the `++` before the `i` in the `for` statement.. the fact that the problem comes only if there is just one element suggests that this could be it.. but i am not sure at all so i am not adding this as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement

```
var chks = document.register.elements['sendto[]'];
```

gets the element (element**s**, if there are more then one) with name`sendto[]`
If there is only one element with name `sendto[]` then you have the reference of that element in `chks`.
If there are more than one element with name `sendto[]`, then `chks` holds the reference to the array of those elements.

When you do this:

```
 for (var i=0;i<chks.length;i++){
```

You try to loop based on `chks.length`. If `chks` is an array (see above: when there are multiple elements by name `sendto[]`), then `chks.length` will hold the number of elements in the array.
If there is only one `sendto[]` element, then chks will hold that element and since the element (`<input type="checkbox" name="sendto[]" value="2" >`) does not have a property called `length`, the browser says *length is indefined*

So you have o differentiate between two scenarios, when there is only one `sendto[]` checkbox and when there are more than one.:

```
var chks = document.register.elements['sendto[]'];
    var hasChecked = false;
//Check whether there is one checkbox or whether there are more    
if(chks.length) 
{
   for (var i=0;i<chks.length;i++)
   {
      if (chks[i].checked)
      {
         hasChecked = true;
         break;
      }
   }
}
else
{
   if(chks.checked)
   {
      haschecked = true;
   }
}
```

<sub>**PS:**

*code gives a message undefined on ValidateForm()* does not convey much. Even for you it is not clear what this means right (That's why you have asked this question). Try to give more details. Any modern browser will give more details on the undefined, the *what* is undefined which line etc. Even pre-historic browsers will tell you the line number where the undefined error was thrown. With those details you can try to find the line and try to see what is happening. You most likely will find out. If you don't, post it to the community here with all these details.</sub>

Comment: @Gurnor: _not working_ = ? You have t give some more details on that. BTW, my intention is not to give you right code but to point you in the correct direction...

Answer (score 1):

```
<script language="javascript">
function validate() {
    var chks = document.getElementsByName('sendto[]');
    var hasChecked = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < chks.length; i++) {
        if (chks[i].checked) {
            hasChecked = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (hasChecked == false) {
        alert("Please select at least one friend.");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it.

```
if(!validate()){
  alert("Please select at least one.");
  return false;
}

function validate(){
  var els=document.getElementsByName('sendto[]');
  for(var i=0;i<els.length;i++){
    if(els[i].checked){
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

You could use validate as an anonymous function.

Comment: While trying this code i am getting this warning: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: @Gurnor I am not using a for each loop. Are you sure it is in my code?  It seems to be working for me.  Is there line number that tells where the error is occurring?